# add a progressbar to vb class using webclient

Tags: vb.net

hi my program uploads images to my server using webclient and xml

i want to add a progress bar when the image is uploading

this is my class:

```
 Public Shared Function uploadToImageUpload(ByVal drawed As String, ByVal ext As String) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of XElement)
            ' Try
            Using w = New WebClient()
                Dim values = New NameValueCollection() From { _
                    {"api_key", "w0omluof1"}, _
                    {"api_secret", "thpnk0z5abi2sk6mun"}, _
                    {"ext", ext}, _
                    {"file", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(drawed))} _
                }
                'Try
                Dim response As Byte() = w.UploadValues("https://imageupload.club/api_image.xml", values)

                Dim response2 As XDocument = XDocument.Load(New MemoryStream(response))

                Dim list As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of XElement) = response2.Elements()

                Return list
            End Using

        End Function
```

and when i upload the image this is the code:

```
Dim info As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of XElement) = DevlopersMyTech.Clases.ImageUpload.uploadToImageUpload(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments) + "\ScreenUploader\temp\screen" + extension, extension)
```

how i can add a progressbar to this function?

Answer (score 0):

The function of uploading the image is executed on the main code, so it will stop the application until it finished.

If you don't wan't this to happen, first you need to pass the current code to a background worker, so it will no stop the application during uploading, if the code have a integer of progress you can use it normally to show the progress, if it don't have, you will probably not able to make an accurate progressbar.

Sorry, I think we can't help you anymore until you give more information about the function itself.

**Edit:** You can Add a progress bar on the main form and add progress to the bar while the code is running, for example, when the function defines the variable 'values' make the ProgressBar to have 15% progress, then when it defines the variable 'response' make the ProgressBar to have 45%, then when it defines the variable 'response2' make the ProgressBar to have 80% and finally when it finished to have 100% progress.

Comment: and this part: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments) + "\ScreenUploader\temp\screen" + extension, extension) is sending to the class the image location and the extension of the image saved

Comment: A Background worker simply executes an operation on a separate thread. All you need to do is do a Drag&Drop from the Items list to the main form, then double click in the new created BackgroundWorker and add the code do you want to execute. Then when you wan't to execute the code inside the background worker you simply write: BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync().

Comment: when it finish uploading i set   BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync() how i can add a progressbar to that ?

Comment: when you use RunWorkerAsync(), the code is runned once. you don't need to use CancelAsync() (that will cancel the upload prematurely).

Comment: the problem is when it finished uploading i show and extra form and then the program lock

Comment: can i use this code?  For offset as Integer = 0 to File.Length Step 1024
    ProgressBar1.Value = CType(offset * ProgressBar1.Maximum / File.Length, Integer)
    Dim chunkSize as Integer = File.Length - offset - 1
    If chunkSize > 1024 Then chunkSize = 1024
    strz.Write(file, offset, chunkSize)
Next
ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum